# Firebase-firestore security rules per document flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase-Firestore denying all requests instead of rejecting one specific document which does not meet the data
Firebase-Firestore security rules

```
allow read: if authenticated() && resource.data.status == true || author(resource.data.creatorid) || admin();
```

what I am trying to achieve is only status = true documents will appear

Error

```
Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

Using package paginate_firestore flutter

```
PaginateFirestore(
  itemsPerPage: 5,
  key: key,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
  itemBuilder: (index, context, documentSnapshot) {
    final data = documentSnapshot.data() as Map?;
    return MainComponent(
      data: data,
    );
  },
  query:
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('members').orderBy('title'),
  isLive: false,
);
```

zero document retrived from firestore. screen is just showing a loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that error is thrown by documents where status is not set to true. Try adding a where clause in your query which fetches documents with status as true.

```dart
query:
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('members').where("status", isEqualTo: true).orderBy('title')
```

When it comes to showing an author their own requests, you can add a where which checks if author ID is equal to currently logged in user's ID.

```dart
query:
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('members').where("authorId", isEqualTo: "currentUserId").orderBy('title')
```

Also try wrapping the conditions with logical or in a bracket:

```
allow read: if authenticated() && (resource.data.status == true || author(resource.data.creatorid) || admin());
```

Comment: Can you please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945869/firestore-security-rules-expressions-meaning