# Firestore security rules ! () Expressions meaning

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What does ! & () Expressions Mean in firestore security rules

```
 allow create: if request resource data size() == 3 &&

(request resource data status == "public" || I request resource data status == "private")
```

And ! Before any statement
I am new to firestore security and  already read many docs but unable to find these two expression meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are basic JavaScript operators:

- `!` negates the expression after it, so that `!true` becomes `false`.
- `&&` performs an AND operation between the expression before and after it, so that `true && true` becomes `true`, but `true && false` becomes `false`.
- `()` group operations together to ensure the order in which they are evaluated. A typical example is when you have AND and OR operations, as I'm never sure which of those takes precedence otherwise: `(true && false) || true`.

I recommend spending some time studying this MDN documentation on [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), as these are quite common in most programming languages.